# Do AWS Api Gateway and Terraform automatically resolve API subpaths?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform, aws-api-gateway

I need to create two *AWS API Gateway* endpoints `/analyze` and `/process` for a project, let's call it `MyProjecy`, with Terraform. 

 This two endpoints should be proxied to the same AWS Lambda. 


 Now, what I'd like to have is a structure like this:

 `/medium`

    |_ `/MyProject`

          |_ `/analyze`

          |_ `/process` 

 My question is: 
since I'm forced to use custom Terraform modules, otherwise I would easily create api resources using 
 `resource "aws_api_gateway_resource"` 
 
could I write into the `path_part` like `/MyProject/analyze` and expect Terraform and AWS to automatically unpack the endpoints? 
Sorry if that's a silly question but I can't find anything on the internet about this. 
Thanks!

Comment: That will depend on the module, but I don't think it's possible.